# equalizing ggplot2 panel heights in a stacked plot with arrangeGrob

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I've got two sets of time-series data that I want to plot in a stacked arrangement. So far I've been able to come up with something like this:

```
library(ggplot2);
library(gridExtra);

t=1:100; s=sin(t/10); c=cos(t/10);
g1=ggplot()+theme_bw()+geom_line(aes(x=t,y=s))+ylab(NULL)
g2=ggplot()+theme_bw()+geom_line(aes(x=t,y=c))+ylab("Cosine")+xlab("Time")

# get rid of the top plot's axis labels
g1=g1+theme(
  axis.text.x=element_blank(),
  panel.margin = unit(0,"null")
  );
g1=g1+labs(x=NULL);

# zero bottom margin of top plot
g1$theme$plot.margin[3]=unit(0,"null");

# zero top margin of bottom plot
g2$theme$plot.margin[1]=unit(0,"null");

# this trick equalizes the width of the two plot panels
g1g=ggplotGrob(g1);
g2g=ggplotGrob(g2);
g1g$widths=g2g$widths

# however, equalizing the heights of the panels is not so simple as
# the following:
# g1g$heights=g2g$heights

g=arrangeGrob(g1g,g2g)

plot(g)   #ggsave("out.svg",g,width=5,height=1.5);
```

The combined plot is shown below. I made it particularly wide and
short so that you could see the problem: `arrangeGrob` equalizes the
plot heights, but doing so makes the plot *panels* have different
heights. The bottom panel gets squished by the *x* axis label and tick
labels on the bottom plot, which the top plot lacks.

[image: combined plot]

Now, I could recycle the trick I used to equalize the widths. Uncommenting the line

```
g1g$heights=g2g$heights
```

yields the following result:

[image: fix height attempt plot]

This is not what I want because of the excessive vertical space which now appears between the plots - I had wanted them to be touching.

I know that I could pass a `heights` argument to arrangeGrob, to specify the relative heights of the plots:

```
g=arrangeGrob(g1g,g2g,heights=c(1,2))
```

But then I have to fiddle with the numbers until it looks right.

I'm wondering if there's an easy way to automatically force just the two panels to have the same height when the final grob is rendered.

Comment: Sorry, I had inline images in my question, but I had to turn them into links because my reputation is too low :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use rbind instead,

```
grid.draw(rbind(ggplotGrob(g1), ggplotGrob(g2)))
```

[image]

and if you want to get rid off the space in-between, it's easier to remove those rows from the gtable than to mess with the plot margins (your manual changes to the theme settings produced an error so I ignored those lines).

```
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(rbind(ggplotGrob(g1)[-(4:6),], ggplotGrob(g2)[-(1:2),]))
```

[image]

Changing the panel heights has to be done in a separate step, e.g. using this little helper function

```
g12 <- rbind(ggplotGrob(g1)[-(4:6),], ggplotGrob(g2)[-(1:2),])

resize_heights <- function(g, heights = rep(1, length(idpanels))){
  idpanels <- unique(g$layout[grepl("panel",g$layout$name), "t"])
  g$heights <- grid:::unit.list(g$heights)
  g$heights[idpanels] <- unit.c(do.call(unit, list(heights, 'null')))
  g
}

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(resize_heights(g12, c(3,1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that is an excellent solution. I especially like that I don't have to manually edit the theme now. By the way, I think `rbind` must have been added within the past five months? Because I had to upgrade gridExtra and ggplot2 to get it to work... I guess I should remember to upgrade more often.

Comment: `rbind.gtable` has actually been in gtable for years, but I've recently exported a slightly modified copy in gridExtra since the original version won't cope with this very common use case.

Comment: I see. By the way, if i want one plot (panel) to be twice as high as the other, is there a way to get this effect using rbind?

Comment: Thank you! Do you mind giving an example of how to edit the heights manually? I think this might be useful to people who come across my question, because the technique I was originally using makes it possible to do such adjustments... I am not very familiar with the 'unit' datatype, and I don't know how powerful it is. For instance, I notice that there is a "grobheight" unit, does this mean that I can set the height (or width) of one grob to 1.5 times the height of another grob in the same table? Or what is the easiest way to do that?

Comment: Thanks again! I just saw that you updated the answer... Sorry I forgot to mark it as "accepted".