# Equalise panel height in mutliplot figure using ggplot2 and grid.arrange

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I equalise the height of the grey panel and at the same time align all panels (even the flipped and reversed)? The problem is that due to the fact that the top plot does have no axis labels etc, the panel height is slightly larger.

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)

# Plot 1
df1 <- data.frame(n = 1:10, y = rnorm(10, 5))
plot1 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x = n, y = y)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")  +
  labs(y = 'AU', x = NULL) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        plot.margin = unit(c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0), "cm"))

# Plot 2
df2   <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100))
plot2 <- ggplot(df2, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  labs(y = 'AU', x = NULL) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        plot.margin = unit(c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0), "cm"))

# Plot 3
df3 <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100))
plot3 <- ggplot(df3, aes(x = x)) +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_histogram() +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        plot.margin = unit(c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0), "cm"))

# Plot 4
df4 <- data.frame(n = 1:10, y = rnorm(10, 4))
plot4 <- ggplot(df4, aes(x = n, y = y)) + 
  scale_y_reverse() +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  labs(y = 'AU', x = 'N') +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0), "cm"))

# Get blank plot
blank <- grid.rect(gp=gpar(col="white"))

# Combine everything into one plot
## Get Grobs
gplot1 <- ggplotGrob(plot1)
gplot2 <- ggplotGrob(plot2)
gplot3 <- ggplotGrob(plot3) 
gplot4 <- ggplotGrob(plot4)

# Align widths
maxWidth = grid::unit.pmax(gplot1$widths, gplot2$widths, gplot4$widths)
gplot1$widths <- as.list(maxWidth)
gplot2$widths <- as.list(maxWidth)
gplot4$widths <- as.list(maxWidth)

# Grid arrange
grid.arrange(grobs = list(gplot1, blank, gplot2, gplot3, gplot4, blank),
             newpage = FALSE,
             ncol = 2,
             widths = c(12, 3))
```

Since I want the middle scatter plot's y-axis to be aligned to the flipped x-axis of the righthand side plot, I can't see how I can use `rbind()` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35911121/equalizing-ggplot2-panel-heights-in-a-stacked-plot-with-arrangegrob) would work for here.

Also, setting the grob heights manually, e.g.

```
gplot4$heights<- gplot1$heights
```

just cuts of the labels. While, the reverse order (`gplot1$heights<- gplot4$heights`) introduces a big gap between the top and the middle plot.

Comment: Have you looked into the patchwork package yet? Or is there some reason to stick to `grid.arrange()` ?

Comment: No, I am not married to gird.arrage but does patchwork corrects for the size that's needed to plot the axis labels etc but nothing more? The problem is only noticeable because the axes are differently sized in my case the labels are even turned off.

Comment: Yeah patchwork attempts to align the panels so that differently sized axis labels etc. falls in line with those.

Comment: I will check that. Thx!

Comment: also check for the `egg` package ! 
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/egg/vignettes/Overview.html